# C# HTML entities from XML string in DataGridView

Tags: c#, html, wpf, xml, datagridview

I'm working with a Web Service that returns an XML string. I need to display the contents of the XML string in a DataGridView to users.

The XML string resembles something like this:

```
 <Field id="13598" type="1">&lt;p&gt;&lt;strong&gt;This &lt;/strong&gt;is our &lt;em&gt;response&lt;/em&gt;&lt;/p&gt;</Field>
```

So far, I've managed to format output that's something like this which is displayed in my DataGridView:

e.g.

```
<p><strong>This </strong>is our <em>statement</em></p>
```

Using *System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlDecode*

Is there a way for me to display the formatted text in the DataGridView?

e.g.

**This** is our *statement*

I'm hoping to achieve useability as the intended users of the program might not be familiar with HTML.

I would've just removed the entities, but I need to retain them as they will be required for writing to an XML string later on as well, due to any editing.

e.g.

```
<p><strong>This</strong> is our updated <em>statement</em></p>
```

I've been toying with the idea of using a new form with a TextBox to enable editing as some of these strings might be much longer than this, and could contain other forms of formatting such as bullet points and the like. I'm not too sure how to go about with this. I'm not entirely sure if what I'm hoping to achieve is possible. If not, are there alternative methods for me to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the [WebBrowser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.webbrowser.aspx) control, and set its content using the [NavigateToString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.webbrowser.navigatetostring.aspx) method